# Form is submitted, but I do not get results in the database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, symfony-3.4

I am new to Symfony and I have a problem with submitting a form with data to the database. So I have done the linking, but somehow the logic does not catches that I have submitted the form.
This is my controller where I check if I have submitted and encrypt my password:

```
    use AppBundle\Entity\UserLogin;
use AppBundle\Form\UserType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;//removed it because it says it is depricated in 3.4
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;



class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="sec_login")
     * @Method("POST")//removed it, because I do not use the namespace anymore
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function loginAction(){
        return $this->render("default/index.html.twig");
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/register", name="sec_register")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request){
        $user = new UserLogin();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $password = $this->get("security.password_encoder")
                ->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword());

            $user->setPassword($password);
            print_r('here');
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute("sec_login", array('form'=>$form->createView()));
        }
        var_dump($user);
        return $this->render("default/index.html.twig");
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/profile", name="user_profile")
     */
    public function profileAction(){
        return $this->render('default/profile.html.twig');
    }
}
```

My entity for the database:

```
 <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Userlogin
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_login")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserLoginRepository")
 */
class UserLogin implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type("\email")
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type("\password")
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=25)
     */
    private $password;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return UserLogin
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return UserLogin
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return UserLogin
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the roles granted to the user.
     *
     * <code>
     * public function getRoles()
     * {
     *     return array('ROLE_USER');
     * }
     * </code>
     *
     * Alternatively, the roles might be stored on a ``roles`` property,
     * and populated in any number of different ways when the user object
     * is created.
     *
     * @return (Role|string)[] The user roles
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getRoles() method.
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
     *
     * This can return null if the password was not encoded using a salt.
     *
     * @return string|null The salt
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
    }

    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user.
     *
     * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
     * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }
}
```

And a form:

```
 <?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\UserLogin;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add("username", TextType::class)
            ->add("email", EmailType::class)
            ->add("password", PasswordType::class)
            ->add("registered", SubmitType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array("data_class" => UserLogin::class));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()//removed that, because some people suggested that this might cause problems
    {
        return 'app_bundle_user_type';
    }
}
```

My template is that:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}


{% block stylesheets %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/indexStyle.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
        <div class="navbar" id="heading">
            <span id="wepart">We</span><span id="conpart">Connect</span>
            <span ><a href="#" class="logger" onclick="expandFunc('login')">Login</a></span>
            <span ><a href="#" class="logger" onclick="expandFunc('register')">Register</a></span>//replaced a href with button, because it was adding # after register in the url
        </div>
        <div id="main">

        <div id="register">
            <form action="{{ path('sec_register') }}" method="post" name="sec_register">

                <input type="text" name="userlogin[username]" placeholder="Username..." /><br/>
                <input type="password" name="userlogin[password]" placeholder="Password..." /><br/>
                <!--<input type="text" name="passwordRe" /><br/>-->
                <input type="email" name="userlogin[email]" placeholder="Email..." /><br/>
                <input type="hidden" name="_crsf_token">
                <input type="submit" name="userlogin[registered]" class="btn btn-light btn-block" value="Sign up" /><br/>

            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="login">
            <form action="{{ path('sec_login') }}" method="post">

                <input type="text" name="_username" placeholder="Username..." onfocus="value='Type username here.'" value="" /><br/>
                <input type="password" name="_password" placeholder="Password..." /><br/>
                <input type="submit" name="logged" class="btn btn-light btn-block" value="Sign in" /><br/>

            </form>
        </div>


ha




        </div>


{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    <script rel="script" src="{{ asset('/js/indexJavascript.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

When I submit the form there is no data in the database and when I `var_dump($user)` I get `NULL` on the properties. I do not get in the `if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())` at all. Please help, I do not find any error and there is no error or exception thrown.
EDIT:
Because you asked for the security.yml. This is it:

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        # Our user class and the algorithm we&#39;ll use to encode passwords
        AppBundle\Entity\UserLogin: bcrypt

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:

        database_users:
          entity: { class: AppBundle:Userlogin, property: email }

        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
            #http_basic: ~

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
            #form_login: ~
            form_login:
                check_path: sec_login

                login_path: sec_login
    #access_control:
    #    - { path: ^\register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONIMOUSLY }
```

But honestly the problem is with the registration form. And I think it might have something to do with that both of the forms are in one page as you can see guys. The form does not get submitted at all, but I submit it. Ran a check in the if statement adding `if($form->isSubmitted() or 1)` and it says that I am trying to insert null values on my fields in the database that are mandatory. Please help.
Some of the `var_dump($form->getErrors());` (couldnt post the whole thing, because even pastebin says it is too long and gives error on the request):

https://pastebin.com/7YB9CicG

Comment: `var_dump($form->getErrors())` after submitting the form

Comment: @Domagoj If I put the var_dump that you suggested on the place of var_dump($user) (that is in the controller) I get redirected in page where loads random text and in the end the page crashes.

Comment: Put it just below this line `$form->handleRequest($request);`
Also, the name attributes don't seem to be in sync. `_username !== username`

Comment: @Domagoj I put the line after `$form->handleRequest($request)` and it is the same thing, lots of text loads and it never stops and just eats from my ram. It is something like this: `object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormErrorIterator)#579 (2) { ["form":"Symfony\Component\Form\FormErrorIterator":private]=> object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form)#600 (13) { ["config":"Symfony\Component\Form\Form":private]=> object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder)#596 (28) { ["children":"Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder":private]=> array(0) { } ["unresolvedChildren": ... and so on `

Comment: That text should tell you what's wrong. It's a dump of form errors if there are any and there probably are because you've said it, the form doesn't pass the `if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())` condition. Dump each of these separately just like you did with `$form->getErrors()` and see which one returns `true`. Also, I'd like to offer more help if you'd just paste everything from the `var_dump($form->getErrors())`

Comment: I just noticed you are using `userlogin[email]` for the input element's name attribute but not for the submit input element. That could cause your form not to be submitted. Try adding `userlogin[submit]` for name attribute of submit input element.

Comment: You can also try to pass the form as the second argument to `render()` like `render(template, ['form' => $form->createView()] )` and in your twig template do `{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}` and then try to submit it.

Comment: Have you configured security to handle logins? Please post your `config/packages/securty.yaml` file. If that file specifies a custom authenticator script, then post that here as well.

Comment: If you haven't already done so, you should probably read and follow the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

Comment: @ehymel I just pasted the security.yml, but I have problems with the register form.

Comment: @Domagoj Can the error be that I am on the same url when submitting the forms(in the case localhost:8000/), because login and registration are meant to be on the same place(in all the tutorials I see making the registration and the login on different places)

Comment: You're using different URL's in each form's action for each controller method respectively, so I doubt that's the problem. Follow the instructions in 5th comment from the top, that should narrow the stuff for us to help you.

Comment: @Domagoj I have dumped both of them separately like that : `var_dump($form->isSubmitted()` and `var_dump($form->isValid())`) both return `bool(false)`

Comment: @Ivanp, I see now that when you said "I submit the form" you meant when you submit the "register" form. You are right, the security stuff has nothing to do with your question and you can remove all of that. Sorry about that, but your question was not clear to me on a first pass.

Comment: I think it would be helpful, just to eliminate possible sources of error, to not try to build your own forms in the template. Instead take the suggestion from Domangoj and use symfony to build the form (7th comment from the top).